# pushd, popd vs cd, cd- in bash and zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, cd-command, pushd

Is there a difference between the behavior of pushd/popd in bash vs zsh? It seems in zsh cd, cd- behaves exactly the same as pushd/popd (which adds/pops directory automatically when cd) while in bash cd doesn't affect the dir stack.

If someone can give me a pointer that would be great.

Comment: I can only speak to bash: using `cd` sets the shell variable `OLDPWD` to the previous directory, and `cd -` gets translated to `cd "$OLDPWD"`.

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks. Does that mean in bash cd has nothing to do w/ pushd/popd?

Comment: I just checked, and `pushd` also sets `OLDPWD`

Comment: And the dirstack, returned by `dirs` always holds the PWD as the first element

Comment: yes, but it also makes a lot sense if cd doesn't touch dir stacks which is managed by pushd/popd in bash.

Comment: `cd` alters `${DIRSTACK[0]}`, so it does affect the top of the dirstack set by pushd

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It depends. In `zsh` you can configure `cd` to push the old directory on the directory stack automatically, but it is not the default setting.

As far as I can tell `zsh` with default settings behaves very similar to `bash`:

- `cd somedir`

  - change directory to `somedir`
  - save the original directory in `OLDPWD`
  - set `PWD="somedir"`
  - replace top element of the directory stack (as shown by `dirs`) with `somedir` (the number of elements on the stack does not change).
- `cd -`:

  - change directory to `$OLDPWD`
  - swap values of `PWD` and `OLDPWD`
  - modify the top element of the directory stack to reflect (the new) `PWD`
- `pushd somedir`:

  - change directory to `somedir`
  - save original directory in `OLDPWD`
  - set `PWD="somedir"`
  - push `somedir` onto the directory stack (extending it by one element)
- `popd`:

  - save original directory in `OLDPWD`
  - remove first element of the directory stack
  - change directory to the new top element of the directory stack
  - set `PWD` to the new top element of the directory stack

**Note:** Whether the present working directory is considered an element of the directory stack differs between `zsh` and `bash`. I used `bash` as reference for the above lists.

- In `bash` the present working directory is considered to be the top element of the directory stack. The `man 1 bash` says:

  > **`pushd [-n] [dir]`**
  >
  > […] Adds `dir` to the directory stack at the top, making it the new current working directory as if it had been  supplied as the argument to the `cd` builtin. […]

  Printing `DIRSTACK` (`echo ${dirstack[@]}`) confirms that the first element is identical to `$PWD`.
- In `zsh` the present working directory is not part of the directory stack (but still shown with `dirs`). `man 1 zshbuiltins` says:

  > **`pushd [ -qsLP ] [ arg ]`**
  >
  > […] Change the current directory, and push the old current directory onto the directory stack.  In the first form,  change the current directory to arg. […]

  Printing `dirstack` (`echo ${dirstack[@]}`) and comparing it to the output of `dirs` should show that the `PWD` is not part of `dirstack.

In both shells `dirs` prints the present working directory as the first element. Also in both shells, the directory stack element with the index `1` refers to the directory which was current before the last `pushd`. That is because arrays in `zsh` are usually numbered from `1`, while they are numbered from `0` in `bash`. So there is little practical difference

---

As said above, this behavior can be modified in `zsh`.

If you set the `AUTO_PUSHD` option in `zsh` (`setopt autopushd`) `cd somedir` behaves like `pushd somedir`, the previous directory is pushed onto the directory stack automatically. This is probably the case on your machine. You can run `setopt` to get a list of options that are not set the default way. See, whether `autopushd` appears in the list.

But this does not modify `cd -` to behave like `popd`. Instead it just pushes `$PWD` onto the directory stack, and changes directory to `$OLDPWD`. That means repeatedly calling `cd -` will actually grow the directory stack (`($PWD $OLDPWD $PWD $OLDPWD $PWD …)`). If it actually does behave exactly like `popd` on your system, I would suggest if `cd` is actually the builtin (`whence -v cd`); it is possible that its replaced with an alias or function.

As the directory stack will grow rather quickly with `AUTO_PUSHD` enabled, you can limit its size by setting the parameter `DIRSTACKSIZE` to the desired maximum size.
You can also prevent duplicates by setting the `PUSHD_IGNORE_DUPS` option.
For more options have a look at [the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Changing-Directories).

Comment: what is the purpose of the directory stack other than looking at it via `dirs`?

Comment: @Xerus It allows to go back to previously visited directories with `popd` without the need to type (or even know) the path.

Comment: Can example be added here?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk I am not quite sure what the example should show other that what is already in the text (but as code). Anything I can think of now would only lengthen the answer but would not add any information.

Comment: Can use e.g. `pushd directory; pushd subdirectory`. At the end you'll be in `./directory/subdirectory`.  A popd takes you back to `./directory` and another popd takes you to `.`

However `cd directory; cd subdirectory; cd -; cd -` leaves you in `./directory` no matter how many `cd -` commands you use because there is only ONE "OLDPWD" saved.

Comment: For those using [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), the `'directory'` module sets `AUTO_PUSHD`, sneakily. You can comment that out here: `~/.zprezto/modules/directory/init.zsh`