# Navigating the file system: Difference between CD and PUSHD

Tags: shell, cd-command, pushd

Being very novice in navigating the file system, I always use the CD command line to change directories.

I just find out that there is another command called: PUSHD

I am having hard time to understand the difference between the two.  Can some please explain me the difference between the two with a real example scenario?

Thank you so much

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for and is one of the best explanation I've ever found about an argument http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272965/pushd-popd-vs-cd-cd-in-bash-and-zsh

Comment: @Echoes_86 thanks I will read the article